# Ensuring a record has all relationships, not any

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have a linqpad script I am working on and it works but the problem is that it uses `.AsEnumerable()` which calls the collection into memory.  There could be thousands of these some day, so I would like to keep everything deferred as much as possible.

I am trying to simply perform a check to make sure if I pass `new long[] { 2, 4 }` to the function, then any *Experiences* that have **both** IDs 2 and 4 will be returned.

Previously, I was using only the `.Contains()` but this would return *Experiences* that have **either** 2 or 4.

Is there a better way to write this code so that it would return an `IQueryable<Experience>` rather than a `List<Experience>` so I don't have to load all results into memory in order to perform the string concat?

```
void Main()
{
    var AllExperiences = new List<_Experience>();
    AllExperiences.Add(new _Experience { Id = 1, Name = "Experience 1" });
    AllExperiences.Add(new _Experience { Id = 2, Name = "Experience 2" });

    AllExperienceTags.Add(new _ExperienceTag { ExperienceId = 1, TagId = 2 });
    AllExperienceTags.Add(new _ExperienceTag { ExperienceId = 1, TagId = 4 });
    AllExperienceTags.Add(new _ExperienceTag { ExperienceId = 2, TagId = 2 });

    var experiences = FilterBySelectedTags(AllExperiences, new[] { 2, 4 }.ToList());

    experiences.Dump();
}

public List<_ExperienceTag> AllExperienceTags = new List<UserQuery._ExperienceTag>();

// Define other methods and classes here
public List<_Experience> FilterBySelectedTags(List<_Experience> experiences, List<int> selectedTagIds)
{
    var filteredExperiencesTags = AllExperienceTags.Where(x => selectedTagIds.Contains(x.TagId));

    var obj = filteredExperiencesTags.OrderBy(x => x.TagId).GroupBy(x => x.ExperienceId).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
    {
        ExperienceId = x.Key,
        ExpTags = string.Join(", ", x.Select(y => y.TagId))
    });

    var filteredTags = obj.Where(x => x.ExpTags == string.Join(", ", selectedTagIds));

    // make sure all the selected tags are found in the experience, not just any
    return experiences.Where(x => filteredTags.Select(y => y.ExperienceId).Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
}

public class _Experience
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class _ExperienceTag
{
    public int ExperienceId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the declaration of the class `Experience`?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Updated the question with completely isolated code.  If you run it, it will return one result.  If you change the second parameter from `{ 2, 4 }` to `{ 2 }` it will return two results as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Experience` entity should have a navigation property to `ExperienceTags`:

```
public virtual ICollection<ExperienceTag> ExperienceTags{get;set;}
```

If that is the case this should work:

```
var query= from e in Experiences
           let experienceTagIds=e.ExperiencesTags.Select(et=>et.TagId)
           where selectedTagIds.All(x=>experienceTagIds.Contains(x))
           select e;
```

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried this in a different way using `.All()` but it didn't work.  Thanks for sharing this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming experiences, has a navigation property Tags on it, then you can do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var experiences = Experiences.FilterBySelectedTags(new long[] { 2, 4 });

    experiences.Dump();
}
public static class ExperienceExtensions {
  public static IQueryable<Experience> FilterBySelectedTags(this IQueryable<Experience> experiences, IEnumerable<long> selectedTagIds)
  {
    return experiences.Where(e=>selectedTagIds.All(id=>e.Tags.Any(t=>t.TagId==id)));
  }
}
```

Comment: according with your solution `Tags` is a navigation property, you should use `Any(x=>x.TagId==id)` instead `Contains`, but I think that is not going to work at that deep level, that's why I use `let` in my solution, because EF needs to work with primitive values at that level if my mind doesn't fail me

Comment: @octavioccl Ah, yes you are correct.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.  Mostly just to show how to use extension methods with LINQ and how to make them chainable.